# How can I use an external script in my vue methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When a User registers i need to send them an confirmation email using vue.js.

I want to use this scrip provided by https://www.smtpjs.com/
How can i make use of this "Email.send" Method within my vue.js application

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
Email.send({
    Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
    Username : "username",
    Password : "password",
    To : 'them@website.com',
    From : "you@isp.com",
    Subject : "This is the subject",
    Body : "And this is the body"
}).then(
  message => alert(message)
);
```

I want it to be like

```
  export default {
    name: 'landing',
    data () {
      return {
        component: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      sendEmail(){
        Email.send({
          Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
          Username : "username",
          Password : "password",
          To : 'them@website.com',
          From : "you@isp.com",
          Subject : "This is the subject",
          Body : "And this is the body"
        }).then(
          message => alert(message)
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That should work so long as you have the `<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">` in your index.html

Answer (score 1):

The script must have an export, so you could download the script and modify it like this:

```
export var Email = {
  ... code ...
};

export default Email;
```

Then in your component, you import it like this:

```
import Email from './smtp.js';
```

With that you should be able to access its functions.